# Is there any expression for "non-oclock hours"?

Tags: phrase-requests

For hours like "9h00", we use "o'clock", but is there any expression that can refer to hours like "9h15", "14h45", etc... ? I want to use a single general expression to refer to these hours

Example : "9h15" and "14h45" are ..., but "9h00" and "17h00" are exact hours

Comment: Hi! Have you come across the terms - "a quarter past noon", "half past nine" etc?

Comment: In modern parlance it is only for exact hours that *o'clock* is used, being a shortened version of the now-archaic *of the clock*. A cursory look through the OED reveals no examples of the term being used for parts of hours, even for half-hours.

Comment: Do you mean everything but the full hours? I'd suggest uneven times.

Comment: @Helmar The trouble with using 'uneven times' is that it isn't a generally accepted usage and would be heavily context dependent to be understood. I can easily imagine 'uneven times' being taken to mean 'all the times which don't fall in an hour with an even number'. Also, it isn't equivalent to 'o'clock' in that we don't talk of the 'o'clock hours' collectively.

Comment: "Half past the hour", "Quarter to the hour", etc. might be found useful to OP, since they aren't attached to any specific time.

Comment: But "half past the hour" can only refers to hours like "HH:30", not to every hours in the format "HH:[1-59]"

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't sure if you were looking for *any time not HH:00* or *a specific minute in any hour*.

Comment: Are you looking for a term for timings that are *always* a multiple or quanta of 15 minutes? Or any time that is not on the hour?  Your OP examples are 15 and 45; your comment suggests 1-59

Comment: I'm looking for an expression for any time that's not on the hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use ***fractional hour***.

dictionary.com:

> [**fractional**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fractional)
>   *adjective*
>
> **1.** pertaining to fractions; comprising **a part** or the parts **of a unit**; constituting a fraction : fractional numbers.

A usage example:

> The University of Oklahoma [Fractional Hour Conversion Chart](https://ou.edu/content/dam/cas/chem/docs/payroll-and-personnel/hourly-conversion.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use the numbers and allow the context to indicate that it's a time.

"The class will assemble at nine fifteen"
"The next bus will arrive at three forty five"

Add "tomorrow morning", "this afternoon" as applicable to remove the 24 hour ambiguity.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for an expression that can group all these "non-oclock hours". I want to use the same general expression to refer to "9h15" or "23h40"

Comment: There isn't one, or if there is, it's a term that's so obscure that it'll confuse most people.  They're just "times" which includes the "top of the hour" times.